# Large list in android?

Tags: android, random

I want to pick an entry randomly from a large list (about a 1000 entries). What is the best way of keeping that large list in my app? Should I put it into a large string array? Will it slow down my program too much when tried to randomly pick a string? 
Thanks!

Comment: How about using SQLite database? Much better than loading the entire 1000 entries into the RAM!

Comment: You can save it in SQLite DB.

Comment: okay thank you! i have never used a SQLite DB before so i am going to have to look up how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, 1000 strings is not a particularly large array size. Whether this is a lot of memory depends on whether the strings are long.

As to picking one at random, the number of elements should not be a factor at all in terms of how long it will take to pick one. Just generate a random integer between 0 and 1000 (exclusive) and pick the one at that index.

```
Random random = new Math.Random(); // done once only

int randomIndex = random.nextInt(1000); // each time you need an index
```

Comment: okay perfect! I am going to have probably 5 different lists all of 1000 entries, you dont think simply having those string arrays on the app will slow it down at all? Sorry i am new to this so i was unsure

Comment: @Hockeyman271 - Unless your strings are unusually long, 5,000 of them won't be a problem at all. What's the average string length?

Comment: so is it alright to declare my string array in strings.xml? or can i even declare it rite on the activity.java?

Comment: @Hockeyman271 - You can declare five 1000-element string arrays in your resources; that's probably the most "Android-ish" way of doing it. You can also declare them directly in Java code. (I'd be tempted to declare them in a separate class from the activity itself, just as a matter of style.) Did you mean that each string is 700 characters long on the average?

Comment: oh no i meant the arrays, each string is probably 10 characters long, how would i do it in a separate class? would i just use an intent to send the data back to my main activity?

Comment: @Hockeyman271 Just declare a class with a static member for each array (or a static member that is an array of arrays). For instance: `public class MyStrings { public static final String[] array1 = { "hello", "there", "world", . . . }; public static final String[] array2 = {...}; /* etc. */ }`. Then you can access each array as `MyStrings.array1`, etc. No need for intents or anything special; it's just static data accessible throughout your application code.

Comment: That works beautifully for organization! The only problem is here  Resources res = getResources();
            myString = res.getStringArray(array_city.array1);
            String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            t1.setText(q);
The "getStringArray" is giving me a error code? it says it cant be a String [] but that doesnt make any sense to me

Comment: @Hockeyman271 You'd call `getStringArray` if you stored your string arrays as resources. If the string arrays are hard-coded in Java, then you don't need to access the resources at all. Just use them as is.

Answer (score 0):

1000 entries are not a large list if we talk about say integers and short strings, if its complex objects I really like [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) for database persistence.